# Why we assign a rotation transformation and not any other when we derive Lorentz factor

Tags: special-relativity

I can't truly understand why when we derive Lorentz factor we should assume that the transformation of coordinates is rotational one.

In the book "Relativity demystified" they say that: "In some sense we would like to think of this transformation as a rotation". And they come to the next equations:

$$x'=x\cos(\phi)-y\sin(\phi)$$
$$y'=-x\sin(\phi)+y\cos(\phi)$$

So to satisfy these equations they choose for coefficients of linear transformation $A,B,C,D$ next values: $$A=D=\cosh(\phi)$$ $$B=C=-\sinh(\phi)$$

I shall notice that the conditions which bounded these coefficients were next: $$D^2-B^2=1$$ $$A^2-C^2=1$$ $$CD=AB$$
It is understandable why they chose to manipulate with hyperbolic functions (because $\cosh^2(\phi)-\sinh^2(\phi)=1$). But the choice of the signs for these functions comes only from the assumptions that our transformation is rotational and the signs for values of coefficients based only on this.

So I dont understand why the transformation should satisfy rotational matrix. And this is an important part. Please could you show me simple example why this is true and why we should choose rotational transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume that the two sets of coordinates are related by transformations that preserve the metric, namely all the matrices $\Lambda$ such that $g' = \Lambda^{T}g\Lambda = g$. This follows in turn from the assumptions that the speed of light does not depend on the reference frame of the observer.
Hyperbolic rotations are a special case of the above.

Comment: And why we have chosen exactly this special case and not the other? Why this case led to the right answer?

Comment: It is the simplest non-trivial case (the trivialest case would be the translations, for example) of two reference frames with same origin only moving in the $x$-direction with respect to each other.

Comment: Ok, now I got this. It is because the only possible transformations with preserved metric is translation and rotation, and for Pseudo-Euclidian space the rotation is made with hyperbolic functions.

Comment: @MrBubbleHubble: Translations do not preserve the metric.

Comment: @WillO They obviously do, the Poincaré group being in fact $\mathbb{R}^{4}\rtimes \textrm{SO}(1,3)$.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco:   Fix a basis.  What is the Lorentz inner product of $(1,0,0,0)$ with itself?   What is the Lorentz inner product of the translated vector $(1,0,0,1)$ with itself?

Comment: @GennaroTedesco:  The Poincare group includes translations of Minkowski space.  But here we are talking about translations of a *tangent space* to Minkowski space, at a fixed event.

Comment: @WillO I do agree on the latter point, although Poincaré transformations are intended as transformations between different charts of a manifold.